# Editor isnt focusable when inside swiper slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js, monaco-editor

I'm using the package **swiper/react** to create a two-panel view that the user can swipe between. I am also using the package **@monaco-editor/react** so my user can write code.

The issue that I'm facing is that when I put the editor inside the swiper slide, the user can't click on the editor or type in anything. I've theorized this is because of the swiper component. In the below code, I have two instances of the Editor. One that's in the swiper slide and one that's outside of it. You'll notice that the Editor thats outside of the swiper works perfectly but the one that's inside doesn't. Any help is appreciated

```js
import Editor, { loader } from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";


function Index() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div style={{ height: "400px" }}>
            <Editor
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              options={{
                minimap: { enabled: false },
                readOnly: false,
                overviewRulerBorder: false,
                padding: { top: 25 },
                lineDecorationsWidth: 0,
                selectionHighlight: false,
                occurrencesHighlight: false,
                tabSize: 2,
                fontSize: 14.5,
              }}
              className="code-editor-window"
            />
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div>
            <h1>Test Slide</h1>
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
      <br />
      <div style={{ height: "400px" }}>
        <Editor
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          options={{
            minimap: { enabled: false },
            readOnly: false,
            overviewRulerBorder: false,
            padding: { top: 25 },
            lineDecorationsWidth: 0,
            selectionHighlight: false,
            occurrencesHighlight: false,
            tabSize: 2,
            fontSize: 14.5,
          }}
          className="code-editor-window"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Swiper component might be interfering with the event handling and focus management of the editor component.

```
import Editor, { loader } from "@monaco-editor/react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Index = () => {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      editorRef.current.layout();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper onSlideChange={() => editorRef.current?.layout()}>
        <SwiperSlide>
          // rest of your code.
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

The useEffect hook trigger the editor's layout refresh when the component mounts.

Comment: I've tried something similar and just tried your implementation as well, unfortunately its no good

Comment: Please let me know more details about your situations.